Omitting the index and bounds of summation
I'm writing a manuscript in Biology and need to write an equation that uses the following summation:
$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i_{\beta_1}} * \sigma_{\beta_2}$
The size reduction of the terms due to the different subscript levels make it a bit hard to read in my opinion. I was wondering if it's usually accepted in academia to shorten this notation as follows:
$\displaystyle\sum \alpha_{\beta_1} * \sigma_{\beta_2}$
Note that the context of the study makes it clear that I'm using the sum of all available $\alpha$.

"...the context of the study makes it clear..." : for what it's worth, what I usually do in such a situation, is add an explanatory note, immediately after the summation, in English, explaining what the summation is supposed to represent.

In that summation as written the $\sigma$ factors are the same for every term in the summation. You could write something like
$$
\sigma \sum_{\alpha \in A} \alpha
$$
and avoid subscripts altogether.
I don't understand how the $\beta$'s occur. You need more context and perhaps better notation.
